# Functions in Model object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it acceptable to call methods of a Model object to retrieve data in the View?

Example:
Suppose I have a search screen which allows users to search for records by companies.

The list of companies may be dynamic and be limited by each user.

Or is it better to perform this action in the Controller?

Comment: Suggested reading: [The Three Models of ASP.NET MVC Apps](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/the-three-models-of-asp.net-mvc-apps/)

Comment: Thanks for the link @Oded

"In ASP.NET MVC, the input model can be envisaged as a collection of classes that model any data coming your way through an HTTP request. **'The input model is made of simple data transfer objects—just properties and no methods.'** Input model classes are used by controller methods as a way to receive posted data parameters or data being passed on the query string or HTTP headers. Here’s an example of a controller method leveraging a class in the input model:"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link @Oded

> "In ASP.NET MVC, the input model can be envisaged as a collection of
>   classes that model any data coming your way through an HTTP request.
>   **'*The input model is made of simple data transfer objects—just properties and no methods.*'** Input model classes are used by
>   controller methods as a way to receive posted data parameters or data
>   being passed on the query string or HTTP headers. Here’s an example of
>   a controller method leveraging a class in the input model:"

So if we wish to adhere to the MVC Pattern we should not use methods in our models for the purpose of dynamically retrieving data.